# SimpleDateFormat ignoring TimeZone when also present in String

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-format

Java's [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) allows you to specify a [TimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZoe-java.util.TimeZone-) to be used when parsing a String to a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

This works as you'd expect when the String doesn't contain a timezone, but when a timezone is present it appears to do nothing.

The documentation doesn't seem to really explain how the TimeZone is used, either.

Example Code:

```
public class DateFormatTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException {
         testBoth("HH:mm", "13:40");
         testBoth("HH:mm z", "13:40 UTC");
    }

    private static void testBoth(final String dateFormatString, final String dateString) throws ParseException {
        // First, work with the "raw" date format
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatString);
        parse(dateFormat, dateString);

        // Now, set the timezone to something else and try again
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatString);
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
        parse(dateFormat, dateString);
    }

    private static void parse(final DateFormat dateFormat, final String dateString) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Parsed \"{0}\" with timezone {1} to {2}", dateString,
        dateFormat.getTimeZone().getDisplayName(), dateFormat.parse(dateString)));
    }
}
```

Example Output:

```
Parsed "13:40" with timezone Greenwich Mean Time to 01/01/70 13:40
Parsed "13:40" with timezone Pacific Standard Time to 01/01/70 22:40
Parsed "13:40 UTC" with timezone Greenwich Mean Time to 01/01/70 14:40
Parsed "13:40 UTC" with timezone Pacific Standard Time to 01/01/70 14:40
```

Note how for the first example, the Date changes - but for the second, it does not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818533/parsing-timezone-from-a-string-with-offset-using-simpledateformat

Comment: Tip: `PST` is not a real time zone. Real time zone names have the format `Continent/Region` such as `America/Los_Angeles`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `DateFormat`. Those classes are notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter`, `LocalTime` and `OffsetTime`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2019 nobody should care why the `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone` classes behave the way they do since we should have given up on using those classes many years ago. Basil Bourque has given you the answer that you should want. This answer will try to satisfy your curiosity, but please don’t use it for getting `SimpleDateFormat` to behave. You’ll be much better off *not* using that class.

I am assuming that your JVM time zone is Europe/London (we shall see that this matters). When I set my time zone this way and my locale to UK, I can reproduce your results exactly.

> Parsed "13:40" with timezone Greenwich Mean Time to 01/01/1970, 13:40

Parsing 13:40 in your default time zone gives 13:40 in your default time zone, no surprises. Since Great Britain was at UTC offset +01:00 in the winter of 1970, this time is the same as 12:40 UTC (when not given a date, `SimpleDateFormat` uses the default of Jan 1, 1970). When the output says `Greenwich Mean Time`, it’s a bug.

> Parsed "13:40" with timezone Pacific Standard Time to 01/01/1970, 22:40

In 1970 the West coast of the USA was 8 hours behind UTC, so 9 hours behind Britain. So when you tell `SimpleDateFormat` to assume that 13:40 is in America/Los_Angeles time zone, it parses into a time of 13:40 PST, the same as 21:40 UTC or 22:40 British Time (America/Los_Angeles is how `TimeZone` interprets PST, but it’s deprecated, don’t rely on it.) `MessageFormat` uses your default time zone to print the time, therefore 22:40 is printed.

> Parsed "13:40 UTC" with timezone Greenwich Mean Time to 01/01/1970, 14:40

Since (as mentioned) London was at offset +01:00 at this time, and since `MessageFormat` uses your default time zone, 14:40 is the correct and expected output. `dateFormat.parse(dateString)` parses into a `Date`, another poorly designed and long outdated class. A `Date` is a point in time and cannot hold a UTC offset (contrary to the `OffsetTime` class that Basil Bourque is correctly using). And your observation is correct: `SimpleDateFormat` uses the `UTC` from the string for interpreting 13:40 into a point in time (not its time zone setting). `MessageFormat` has no way of knowing that the time had earlier been parsed from 13:40 UTC.

> Parsed "13:40 UTC" with timezone Pacific Standard Time to 01/01/1970, 14:40

Since `SimpleDateFormat` uses the `UTC` from the string for interpreting 13:40 into a point in time, we get the same time as above.

Answer (score 1):

## Wrong types

You are using the wrong data types, trying to fit a time-of-day value into a type that holds a time-of-day and a date and an offset-from-UTC (of zero). [Square peg, round hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole).

Also, that `java.util.Date` class is terribly designed and implemented. It was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

## Time-of-day: `LocalTime`

> "13:40"

Simply parse as a `LocalTime` object.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "13:40" ) ;
```

If you want to combine with a date and a time zone to determine a moment, apply a `LocalDate` and `ZoneId` to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( today , lt , z ) ;
```

To see that same moment in UTC, extract a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

## Time-of-day with offset-from-UTC: `OffsetTime`

> "13:40 UTC"

A time-of-day with a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) does not actually make sense. Without a date, there is no meaningful way to think of a time as it relates to a particular time zone. No one has been able to explain to me an example of how that could logically hold meaning. Every attempt I have heard argued actually involves an implied date.

Nevertheless, the SQL standard committee decided in their wisdom to define a `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` data type. And so, to support that, the *java.time* classes include a matching class, [`OffsetTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetTime.html).

Unfortunately I cannot find a formatting pattern that works to parse the SPACE and `UTC` at the end of your input. So as a workaround, I suggest replacing those characters with the single `Z` character. So `"13:40 UTC"` becomes `"13:40Z"`. The `Z` means UTC and is pronounced “Zulu”. This format is handled by default, so no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "13:40 UTC".replace( " UTC" , "Z" ) ;  // "13:40 UTC" becomes "13:40Z".
OffsetTime ot = OffsetTime.parse( input ) ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both modern and legacy) and in standard SQL.]

Comment: I am aware of the “modern” Date classes in Java but this does not help to explain the behaviour I am experiencing.

Comment: @Jakg My point is that your Question is moot. There is no reason to be wrestling with those terrible date-time classes. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on those classes when they adopted JSR 310. So should you. Surely you have more productive things to do than try to understand the flawed design of obsolete classes no longer used.